# Handling error messages with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

Is there a recommended way to keep error messages within the requested objects from a webservice?

In some examples I see the webservices returning a wrapper class containing some HTTP error codes, others hold messages of .NET-exceptions. On the other hand  there are the examples returning the plain objects or list of objects.

Comment: Hello Bert, I have removed the preamble, *as I suggested before*. People are more inclined to answer your question if it doesn't have read lots of extraneous information. This question is now precise. Your other questions will still be found with the other ServiceStack questions, without being linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error handling can appear confusing at first. The [official documentation is here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling). But essentially ServiceStack tries to return errors in a consistent way so your client always knows how to handle them. You should throw exceptions in the normal c# way, ServiceStack will catch these and encapsulated it in a `ResponseStatus` object, which looks like this:

```cs
public class ResponseStatus 
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    public List<ResponseError> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

*[Full definition here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ResponseStatus.cs)*

So you will receive a response object that contains a property called `ResponseStatus` having the populated `ResponseStatus` object above.

Things to note:

- The `StackTrace` property will only be included if you enable `debug` mode in your ServiceStack AppHost Config. i.e:

  ```cs
  SetConfig(new HostConfig { DebugMode = true });
  ```

  This will be the .NET exception you are referring to, and is shown conditionally depending if `DebugMode` is set.

  ---
- The `Errors` list of `ResponseError` is only populated for validation error failures. This will be the list of validation errors. Which is why you see in some examples a plain error response *(i.e. not a validation error)*, and a response with a list of errors attached *(validation error)*. You should also read the section about [validation in the documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation). The format of `ResponseError` object is this:

  ```cs
  public class ResponseError
  {
      public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
      public string FieldName { get; set; }
      public string Message { get; set; }            
  }
  ```

  The `ErrorCode` and `Message` of the `ResponseStatus` object will be taken from the first item of the `Errors` list.

Where things get confusing for some people is how, to include the `ResponseStatus` as a property of your expected response request.

So assuming your wanted to return a `Person` object such as this:

```
class Person
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

If a validation exception was thrown for a request that returns this `Person` response you may get a JSON response like this:

```js
{
    "ResponseStatus": {
         "ErrorCode": "ShouldNotBeEmpty",
         "Message": "'FirstName' should not be empty",
         "StackTrace": "..."
         "Errors": [
             {
                 "ErrorCode": "ShouldNotBeEmpty",
                 "FieldName": "FirstName",
                 "Message": "'FirstName' should not be empty"
             },
             {
                 "ErrorCode": "ShouldNotBeEmpty",
                 "FieldName": "LastName",
                 "Message": "'LastName' should not be empty"
             },
         ]
    }
}
```

Note that the response object of Person is not included in this response, just an object containing the `ResponseStatus` property. If we want to include the response object with the status we must declare our person class this way:

```cs
class PersonResponse
{
    ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then when an exception is thrown the response will include the response object and it's status:

```js
{
    "FirstName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "ResponseStatus": {
        ...
```

ServiceStack provides you with a lot of control over the error format you return when an exception is thrown, it's best you read through the official documentation I linked to above to understand it. Customisation is more of an advanced topic.

Comment: Very nice and clear answer. I have a question, though : If I cannot edit the Response DTO because its in another DLL that I do not own, it is possible for me to send the name of the thrown exception in some way ?

Comment: @RPDeshaies If you can't modify the DTO response, perhaps you could set a custom header with the details, by overriding the `OnServiceException(IRequest httpReq, object request, Exception ex)` method in your `AppHost`. Then use `httpReq.Response` to set the details of `ex` out to a header. Then you would be able to see that header in your client.